# Modifying counter not work using enzyme and react hooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

halo, I'm now learning react testing with jest and enzyme, and hooks. I found a problem when using decrement and increment at the same time. the decrement not working.

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false);

  const decrement = () => {
    if (count < 1) {
      setErr(true);
    } else {
      setCount((x) => (x -= 1));
    }
  };

  const increment = () => {
    setCount((x) => (x += 1));
  };

  return (
    <div data-test="component-app" className="App">
      <h1 data-test="counter-display">{count}</h1>
      {err && (
        <h1 data-test="error-message" color="red">
          Cant increment below zero
        </h1>
      )}
      <button data-test="increment-button" onClick={increment}>
        Add
      </button>
      <button data-test="decrement-button" onClick={decrement}>
        Dec
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```js
test('should decrement value display', () => {
    const plusButton = wrapper.find('[data-test="increment-button"]');
    const minButton = wrapper.find('[data-test="decrement-button"]');

    plusButton.props().onClick();
    plusButton.props().onClick();
    minButton.props().onClick();
    const counterDisplay = wrapper.find('[data-test="counter-display"]');

    expect(counterDisplay.text()).toBe('1'); // failed -> it always received 2 instead 1.
  });
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your test to pass use `mount` instead of `shallow`;

```
const wrapper = mount(<App/>)
```

and use `simulate('click')` instead of `props().onClick();`:

```
  plusButton.simulate('click');
  plusButton.simulate('click');
  minButton.simulate('click');
```

that's one approach that simulates a rendered dom iteraction.

your test actually fails because at shallow, component is not really rendered as mount. `minButton` has initial App component state reference (which is 0), but it doesnt get its updated state ref on others buttons click. since minButton has the restriction `if (count < 1)` the update state doesnt trigger.

for your test to work as shallow, as you intended, you need to create minButton from wrapper after wrapper's state is already updated:

```
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  const plusButton = wrapper.find('[data-test="increment-button"]');
  
  plusButton.props().onClick()
  plusButton.props().onClick()
  // wrapper state is now 2, hence minButton will be able to update state properly
  const minButton = wrapper.find('[data-test="decrement-button"]');
  minButton.props().onClick()
  const counterDisplay = wrapper.find('[data-test="counter-display"]');

  expect(counterDisplay.text()).toBe("1"); // now works, weee :)
```

Comment: wow, it works. what is the difference between simulate('click') and props().onClick? and why should I mount? I used shallow and increment works good

Comment: I edited the answer, to give better insight. I hope it helps. actually, involved some investigation on my end. if you find that it solves your question It would be nice to accepted it as the answer :). though if you feel still as incomplete and need more clarification feel free to question.

Comment: wonderful, thanks for the explanation @buzatto , I made it an accepted answer